# Padding 1D NumPy array with zeros to form 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
arr=np.array([0,1,0,0.5])
```

I need to form a new array from it as follows, such that every zero elements is repeated thrice and every non-zero element has 2 preceding zeroes, followed by the non-zero number. In short, every element is repeated thrice, zero as it is and non-zero has 2 preceding 0 and then the number itself. It is as follows:

```
([0,1,0,0.5])=0,0,0, [for index 0]
              0,0,1 [for index 1]
              0,0,0 [for index 2, which again has a zero] and
              0,0,0.5
```

final output should be:

```
new_arr=[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.5]
```

np.repeat() repeats all the array elements n number of times, but i dont want that exactly. How should this be done? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick reshape followed by a call to [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) will do it:

```
np.pad(arr.reshape(-1, 1), ((0, 0), (2, 0)), 'constant')
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5]])
```

You'll want to flatten it back again. That's simply done by calling `.reshape(-1, )`.

```
>>> np.pad(arr.reshape(-1, 1), ((0, 0), (2, 0)), 'constant').reshape(-1, )
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,
    0.5])
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this! Can you please explain ((0, 0), (2, 0)) part in it?

Comment: @Ishi Indeed I can. `(0, 0)` is to specify padding for the up and down edges, while `(2, 0)` is to specify padding for the left and right edges. Since we only want padding on the left, we've got to set everything else to 0. `'constant'` implies 0 padding. Glad to help.

Comment: Got it! very nice explanation. Also, reshape(-1,) means we are not specifying the number of rows and columns, they will be same as the original one? Thanks for your help!

Comment: -1 indicates that numpy should automatically determine the length along that axis. You want to specify a 1D array, and -1 is a good way of keeping it generic.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the `pad` idea is to concatenate a 2d array of zeros

```
In [477]: arr=np.array([0,1,0,0.5])
In [478]: np.column_stack([np.zeros((len(arr),2)),arr])
Out[478]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5]])
In [479]: _.ravel()
Out[479]: 
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,
        0.5])
```

or padding in the other direction:

```
In [481]: np.vstack([np.zeros((2,len(arr))),arr])
Out[481]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0.5]])
In [482]: _.T.ravel()
Out[482]: 
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,
        0.5])
```